# Is the "okay" hand gesture now unacceptable to use in class?

Tags: teaching

While teaching a class last week, I made the widely-recognized hand gesture (an open circle with the thumb and index finger, with the other 3 fingers loosely or sharphy extended... I'm not sure exactly how mine looks, as it's like muscle memory and I don't consciously think about the exact shape I'm making) while simultaneously saying "okay...". I can't remember the full sentence but it was something related to the math course I'm teaching.

Now I suddenly learn that it means "white power" to some people (some Americans). To make matters even worse, I'm white, and I make a very similar-looking symbol while indicating 3 things (some use the middle 3 fingers for this; but I've always done it the other way) or counting to a number between 3 and 5 with my fingers.  Good heavens!

Would I possibly get into administrative trouble for doing this, if a student were to report it?

Comment: That entirely depends on the rules and regulations of your institution (I highly doubt you could get in trouble for an innocent gesture, though, unless you actually *are* a proponent of "white power").

Comment: Answers to "Would I possibly" questions are almost always positive. The better questions are "how likely" and "how serious trouble". Accusations generally tend to cause trouble, whether or not they are founded; but the total number of cases in which the trouble was serious and permanent (for reasons as trivial as yours) is rather small (in the US, I could name 2-3 at most; Canada is worse). I suspect the OK-sign panic will be gone the way of the dinosaurs in a year or two, but in the process I have no idea how much havoc it will wreak (most of it, probably, outside academia).

Comment: Note that everything that is happening is happening [just according to keikaku](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/just-according-to-keikaku): The "white power" meaning of the gesture [was invented by 4chan /pol/ in the first place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_(gesture)#Alt-right), probably with the exact goal of causing a moral panic.

Comment: Incidentally, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_(gesture)) suggests this gesture has various other (pre-existing) meanings in different cultures, some of them offensive.  If you plan to do much international travel (which many academics do), you might want to try to get out of the habit of using this gesture anyway.

Comment: In some cultures that is a bit offensive, representing something else that is round and offensive :)

Comment: No one explicitly said that but this sign, for instance in Turkey widely recognized as an insult to male people indicating that they are gay. Of course, given the context, it should be forced too much to try to get an offensive indication from your "OK" gesture.

Comment: It may have started as a joke, but it got this guy suspended from duty: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-45535715 (google shows many other media reports of the incident)

Comment: I wonder why nobody said so already: Add info on your country to the question. The question would not make any sense if asked in some countries.

Comment: 'Thumbs up' has in some countries about the meaning of 'the finger' ('sit on that'). There is probably no gesture that hasn't this risk, so if you want to be sure, don't use any ever.

Answer (score 29):

The whole "White-power" hand sign started as a joke from 4chan or something like that. It was kind of a ploy to get the more gullible liberals all worked up for nothing. It was kind of laughable at first. However, it would seem that it's becoming more and more accepted as an actual WP symbol. I believe that some white-supremacist groups have even ended up adopting it. Still, I wouldn't worry about it as long as it doesn't seem as if you are actually pushing the agenda.

You could always swap it for "thumbs up" or, my favorite, good ol' finger guns.

Comment: +1 for thumbs up, even if you're at my school, because Gig 'Em.

Comment: At my kids' school, you would get in trouble with the hand guns.

Comment: In some cultures, "thumbs up" is an offensive sexual gesture.

Answer (score 10):

Quite aside from the ridiculous white power thing, you might want to consider not using that gesture, as it's easily misinterpreted. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_(gesture)#Negative_connotations) says:

- it's offensive in parts of central and southern Europe;
- it can mean "zero" or "worthless" in France and Belgium;
- in various Mediterranean, Middle-Eastern and South American countries, it denotes the anus generally, can mean "You're an asshole!" and can be homophobic;
- it also has associations with the female genitals;
- in Arab countries, it represents the evil eye and is used as a curse;
- Wikipedia's a bit vague about its use in American Sign Language, where it seems to have a number of different uses, some of which are claimed to be offensive.

Sure, any hand gesture has the potential to be offensive to *someone*<sup>1</sup> and most people will realise you're not trying to be offensive if you make one of these gestures in a non-offensive context while not looking offensive, you're probably not being offensive. Still, the okay gesture does seem more likely to cause confusion ("Why is he looking happy and saying 'asshole'?") than other gestures.

<sup>1</sup> Thumbs up has negative meanings in some places; gesturing "two" by extending the first and second fingers vertically with the back of the hand towards the viewer means "f*** off" in the UK, etc.

Comment: I don't know where Wikipedia got the idea that it can mean "worthless" in France (it isn't clear if the citation refers to the meaning in "Mediterranean countries" or also to France and Belgium). It just means zero. It's a circle. It isn't offensive.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi OK but it's still potentially confusing if you "say" OK and your audience "hears" zero.

Answer (score 8):

It's fine.  Don't keep such track of the latest silliness.  Let it pass.

I do think it is a bit informal.  That is if the teacher calls on you, you should answer him directly.  But signalled across a laboratory or the like, I would have no issue with it.

Comment: OP seems to be the teacher.

Answer (score 6):

As you are teaching maths, then it’s fine when used in conjunction with the material, ie having just completed an exercise with simultaneous equations and asking if it was understood.

However, if you are teaching politics or examining causes of racial tension in a sociology type subject then I would suggest no.

Also, in some countries the "Thumbs up" gesture is not considered polite either... "sit on this..."

Comment: Good point about the importance of context.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an 'okay' sign.  Unfortunately, it seems the reality is that it may be increasingly inappropriate to convey this gesture.

At the very least, it opens the opportunity for misinterpretation and perhaps should be avoided for this reason alone.

In this day and age, it can be wagered that someone will jump on the chance to be offended by the continued use of this gesture.

It should be okay to make the okay sign, though.  It should be.